# getting data using wpdb by comparing some data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to get data(time) by comparing userid and date against a post.
data stored in this form.
meta key
date   -   `03-01-2017`
time   -    `5AM-6AM`
userid    -    `1`

Now when I click on a button I get the date and userid.

```
$(".date").click(function(){

    clicked = this; 
    var dates= $(clicked).closest("ul").find(".getdate").val();
    var item= jQuery(this).closest("li.lia");
    var date = jQuery(item).find("input.getdate").val();
    alert(date);

    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',   // Adding Post method
         url: MyAjax.ajaxurl, // Including ajax file
         data: {"action": "date_time", "date":date, 
         "userid":'<?php echo $uid;?>'}, // Sending data dname to  post_word_countfunction.
         success: function(data){ // Show returned data using thefunction.
         alert(data);
        }
      });
});
```

Then I send this data through ajax to a function date_time.

```
function date_time(){
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'date' AND     meta_value='$date' AND meta_key = 'userid' AND meta_value='$userid'";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    print_r($results);
}
```

here I match userid and date and try to get time but it is showing 0 in alert of ajax success function.

Comment: echo the query and run the query manually on your server and then debug

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19493172/5336818

Comment: I think we need more detail on how you're storing the data in the first place.  Your query won't work because you can't have a single row where `meta_key = 'date'` and `meta_key = 'userid'` (which is what you're requesting).  Can you be clearer as to how the data is stored?  Is it three rows in `$wpdb->postmeta`, one for user, one for date, and one for time?

Comment: yes there are 3 rows for each entry
date -  03-01-2017
time -  5AM-6AM
userid -  1
postid   469

date -  01-01-2017
time -  1AM-2AM
userid -  1
postid   468

data is stored in this way.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to be a completely different question.  It makes all the answers to the original question irrelevant.  Ask a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458857/calling-to-php-function-in-seprate-file-from-ajax-not-working/41458918?noredirect=1#comment70126441_41458918
i have asked a new one. please check this.

Comment: Thanks; I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Try meta query instead of custom query:

[WP Meta Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)

on base of it,

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'date',
            'value' => $date,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
// this array results in no return for both arrays
        array(
            'key' => 'userid',
            'value' => $userid,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);
$the_query  = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question, you'll need a self join on the postmeta table: you need to find and join several rows to get the data you need.

Before that, though, read up on [SQL injection in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) - your code is vulnerable to malicious `POST`ed values.

Try something like (untested, but it should give you the idea):

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT metatime.meta_value
      FROM $wpdb->postmeta metadate
           JOIN $wpdb->postmeta metauser on metadate.post_id = metauser.post_id
           JOIN $wpdb->postmeta metatime on metadate.post_id = metatime.post_id
     WHERE metadate.meta_key = 'date'
       AND metauser.meta_key = 'userid'
       AND metatime.meta_key = 'time'
       AND metadate.meta_value = %s
       AND metauser.meta_value = %d",
    $date,
    $userid);
```

Comment: i think i have some error in ajax because my php function is not called.
    function date_time(){
 echo "something";
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];

i tried to echo but its not working which meant my function is not called by ajax.

Comment: Have you hooked up the Ajax action `date_time` with your PHP function `date_time()`?  With something like `add_action('wp_ajax_date_time', 'date_time');` (and/or `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_date_time', 'date_time');`) - see https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress meta data table is few different. Here all metadata are individual row. so you can not query multiple meta data in same query as like you doing .
But you can do as following. Try this SQL, i think it will be helpful for you.

```
SELECT m1.meta_key as date,
       m1.meta_value as dateval,
       m2.meta_key as userid,
       m2.meta_value as useridval 
  FROM `wp_postmeta` as m1 
       LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as m2 ON m1.post_id = m2.post_id 
 WHERE (m1.meta_key ='date' AND m1.meta_value='$date')
   and (m2.meta_key = 'userid' AND m2.meta_value='$userid')
```