# calling to php function in seprate file from ajax not working

Tags: php, ajax

I want to get data(time) by comparing userid and date against a post. But for testing I am simply calling php function by ajax. I made a separate php file (myscript.php) in which I made a function and echo something like that.

```
function my_action(){
    echo "dasdasasdaaddad";
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    echo $date;
    return $date;
}
```

Now when I click on a button I get the date and userid.

```
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
add_action( 'the_content', 'my_action_javascript' );
function my_action_javascript() { 
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$uid = $current_user->ID;
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(".date").click(function(){

        clicked = this; 
    var dates= jQuery(clicked).closest("ul").find(".getdate").val();
    var item= jQuery(this).closest("li.lia");
    var date = jQuery(item).find("input.getdate").val();
    //var dates = jQuery(item).find("input.getdate").val();


    alert(date);
    jQuery.ajax({

        type:"post",
        url: "<?php $current_url;?>/myscript.php",

    data : {
        'action': 'my_action',
        'date': date,
        'userid': "<?php echo $uid?>"
    },

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    success: function(data) {
            successmessage = 'Data was succesfully captured';
            $("label#successmessage").text(successmessage);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            successmessage = 'Error';
            $("label#successmessage").text(successmessage);
        },
    });
});
</script> 
<?php
}
```

I gave the URL of that file in ajax url.  Now it should print data from myscript.php file but I am getting this result in response from ajax.

```
Got this from the server:0
```

I have checked the network also and it seems good to me.
    ajax is getting userid and date but response is 0.Don't know why?

Comment: Start by working out if the problem's in myscript.php or your ajax. If you change the `$_POST` in myscript.php to `$_GET`, and you go directly to `myscript.php?date=test`, does the output look right?  If so, does that URL match the URL generated by this line: `url: "<?php $current_url;?>/myscript.php",`?

Answer (score 0):

on 
myscript.php page remove function my_action().. because you are not calling this.

```
if you want to call this before that use my_function();

<?php
my_function();
function my_action(){
 echo "dasdasasdaaddad";
$date = $_POST['date'];
echo $date;
return $date;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks but the result is same.
       Got this from the server:0

Comment: can you write on php page  print_r($_POST); and check

Comment: still nothing.
:/

Comment: have you tried with print_r($_POST); on myscript.php page

Comment: yes i have tried it.
    
    print_r($_POST);
    my_function();
     function my_action(){
 echo "dasdasasdaaddad";
$date = $_POST['date'];
   echo $date;
    return $date;
    }

Comment: it was giving me error that url is not defined.
so i make it simple.please check updated question
and now its showing me 404 error in network. 404 Not Found

Comment: hii please check <?php $current_url;?>/myscript.php file is onsame path or not

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your my_action function in myscript.php file. Call your function you will get the your desired result.

```
<?php

function my_action(){
    echo "dasdasasdaaddad";
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    echo $date;
    return $date;
}

my_action();

?>
```